# How to change AWS SDK region in code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aws-sdk

It is necessary to define

```
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1"/>
```

application setting in App.config to specify region to use.

I need to change that programmatically

```
var creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, token);
using (var routes = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonRoute53Client(creds)){}
```

how to specify the region in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the best practice to use more configurable version (i.e. endpoint configured from `web.config/app.config`). For EC2 client, you can do it by the following way:

> ```
> var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("ap-northeast-1"); 
> var awsEC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(region);
> ```

For others reason, you can specify from [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region)

### Resource Link:

1. [How to set the EndPoint / Region for the C# .NET SDK : EC2Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949671/how-to-set-the-endpoint-region-for-the-c-sharp-net-sdk-ec2client)
2. [How to start an Amazon EC2 instance programmatically in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420368/how-to-start-an-amazon-ec2-instance-programmatically-in-net)